# How does Kafka treat negative number in partition in ProducerRecord in Kafka Client 0.10?

Tags: java, apache-kafka

In Kafka Client 1.1.0 a check is placed to not allow negative as `partition` in `ProducerRecord`.

https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/1.1/clients/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/ProducerRecord.java#L73

But I don't see any such check in `ProducerRecord` in kafka client 0.10.0.

https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/0.10.0/clients/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/ProducerRecord.java#L62

Can someone let me know how does Kafka handle the negative number in `partition` in `ProducerRecord` in 0.10? Will the partition be converted to positive number ? If yes can some one point me to the code / logic of the conversion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the 0.10.0 Kafka Producer, a negative number for the partition is also rejected.

The check was not done in `ProducerRecord` like in the recent releases but instead in [`KafkaProducer.partition()`](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/0.10.0/clients/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/KafkaProducer.java#L716-L718) and you would get the following stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid partition given with record: -1 is not in the range [0...0].
at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.partition(KafkaProducer.java:717)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.doSend(KafkaProducer.java:459)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.send(KafkaProducer.java:430)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.send(KafkaProducer.java:353)
```